# Formula for Nodes in a Tree

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I am reading section 1.5.2 in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CA4NDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=cosine%20similarity%20poincare%20disk&source=bl&ots=wEqC9ebB_a&sig=ACfU3U0tbzpCRs7INeieKQtCcOw9qPfQqA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwji-aydw7HqAhUHYcAKHc9nD4QQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=cosine%20similarity%20poincare%20disk&f=false) where they claim that for a tree with branch factor $b$, the number of nodes at distance $R$ from the root is given by

$$N(R)=(b+1)b^{R-1}$$

However, I just don't see this. Let us imagine the following graph:

[image]

The branching factor is $b=4$. When R=0 we are at the root node and there is one node. There are 4 nodes in the first layer (a distance of $R=1$) and 16 in the second layer (a distance of $R=2$). I would therefore say that $N(0)=1, N(1)=4, N(2)=16$ and hypothesise that

$$N(R)=b^R$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think you are right. What they have in mind is obviously a tree in which every node has degree $b + 1$, but this is not the usual definition of "$b$-ary tree", as in binary or ternary tree, and I don't find any proper definition of "$b$-ary tree" in the book. It however probably doesn't matter too much, as what they want is just the asymptotic formula $N(R)\sim b^R$.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check!

Comment: Maybe they're giving you the number of nodes at distance *at most* $R$ from the root?